# How can we use Google Datastore Objectify remotely?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am trying to use Google Objectify for Datastore (https://github.com/objectify/objectify). My app is not hosted on GAE, but I still make use of Datastore, so I need to use the remote API. Right now, I use the low level API and connect successfully like this :

```
DatastoreOptions options = DatastoreOptions.builder()
                .projectId("PROJECT_NAME")
                .authCredentials(AuthCredentials.createApplicationDefaults()).build();
Datastore client = options.service();
```

And the library used is http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-java/0.2.0/index.html. My application defaults for "AuthCredentials.createApplicationDefaults()" is in my home folder in development as well as on the server.

In the doc I saw for Objectify, I did not see anyway of specifying the connection like above, thus no way of telling to use the credentials file in our home folder. The code I see for Objectify is mostly like this `Objectify.ofy()`. So I see no way with this method of telling to use the auth credentials defaults.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you find a workaround ?

Comment: Hello, I decided to have my server hosted on Google Cloud. So I used the even more default way to connect : DatastoreOptions.defaultInstance().service();
Sorry I cannot be of anymore help as I did not find a way to connect remotely... But good luck!!

Comment: I found a workaround. I use the RemoteApi https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi to install a context of a google app engine instance which I created only to do remote queries from my outside app. It's the solution of @stickfigure by the way

Comment: Ok thanks for the info, I'll mark his answer as accepted and try it again on another project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Google App Engine remote api:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi

Answer (score 0):

You could try gcloud-java datastore module.

http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-java/0.2.0/index.html

But I encounter some performance issues on outside of Google Sandbox (GAE-Compute Engine)

Comment: That is exactly what I am using, what I don't know is how I can connect gcloud with Objectify, but thanks.